# How to use xstring predicates inside \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, xstring

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{/}{#1}{images/#1}}
\includegraphics{\abs{/tmp/photo.jpg}}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't compile. Just hangs up.

Comment: xstring commands are not expandable so you can not use them there

Comment: However, you could structure it as follows: `\newcommand\abs[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{/}{\includegraphics{#1}}{\includegraphics{images/#1}}}
\abs{/tmp/photo.jpg}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's sad. Please, post an answer so I can choose it and close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xstring commands are not expandable so you can not use them there –

However, you could structure it as follows:

```
\newcommand\abs[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{/}{\includegraphics{#1}}{\includegraphics{images/#1}}} \abs{/tmp/photo.jpg}
```

However you could add `{images/}` to the graphics path then you would need no test and could do

```
\includegraphics{filename}

\includegraphics{/a/b/c/filename}
```

with the first being found in the `images` subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an expandable command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\abs}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeF { \str_head:n { #1 } } { / } { images/ } #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{\abs{duck}}

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{\abs{/tmp/hello}}

\end{document}
```

and compilation yields

[image]

The relevant part in the log file is

```
<./images/duck.jpg> </tmp/hello.png>
```

which witnesses that the images are loaded from the expected places.